# calculating waste factor for hip roof w/ valley using cedar shakes

Tags: roof, roofing

I've been told that my hip roof would result in a whopping 30% waste factor with cedar shakes, that three additional squares of shakes are needed above the amount required to cover the raw square footage. I do not agree with the calculation and would like to know what I'm overlooking.

Let's assume  my hip roof is exactly 1000 square foot.

There are four hips -- front, west, east, and rear (so five "hip ridges" or "hip junctions" in addition to the main ridge) and there is also a valley.   At a 7.5" exposure there are at present 20 courses of shingles eave to ridge, not including the starter course and the ridge/hip caps.

Here's what I think is the worst case waste scenario: imagine a 12" wide shake being cut in half diagonally and half of it being tossed into the waste pile. That wastage occurs at each of the 20 courses at each hip junction on either side of it. So a full shake is wasted at each course at each hip junction.

5 hip junctions x 20 wasted shakes  =  100 shakes of waste on the diagonal cuts for the hips. An additional 20 wasted shake for the valley, worst case. We're not really going to be cutting the 12" shake in *half* diagonally.

Total waste because of these diagonal cuts, 120 shakes.

At a 7.5" exposure (18" shake with felt interlay) that's about 72 square footage of waste, or approx. 3/4 of a square.

I come up with only a 10% waste factor.